# Automatically mount drive when loggin in via ssh

Tags: cygwin

I want to move user home folder in cygwin to different drive,
i tried and i know that i can just change passwd file and put the path i need , however when i just logged in i cannot access my S drive mounted in windows ( `/cygwin/s` ) and i need to type `mount -a` to get it working
so when i put user home folder to this drive  ( `/cygwin/s/home` ) and try to ssh, it appear that cygwin can access this directory and put user home folder to /tmp

so I'm interested in either executing `mount -a` on connecting user via ssh, or any other workaround for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have commands run each time a user logs in. There are many ways to accomplish it.
One of them is to  add `mount -a` to bash.rc

Comment: thank you, creating `bash.rc` and adding `mount -a` to it worked for me